# Essence of fancy selectors in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So like, let's say i have this input field:

```
<input class="dateP" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Birthday must be a date." data-val-required="Bday is required" id="bday" name="bday" type="text" value="11/16/1990" />
```

The material that i am learning from referenced it by doing it something like this:

`$('input:text.dateP')`

Wherein we can just do something like:

`$('.dateP') //access by class?` to access it.

Can someone explain to me what are the significant differences?

Comment: `$('input:text.dateP')` will specifically look for `<input>` with class `dateP` , `$('.dateP')` will look for all class `.dateP`

Comment: ahhhh i see, so it's more specific? does it affects performance?

Comment: Yes! most likely as far as I have seen/used.

Comment: Not really performance but it depends upon what you are trying to achieve..Only class selector will return multiple elemnts whose class is matching whereas `$('input:text.dateP')` will return more specific elements..

Comment: What's the common practice? As beginner, it would be easy if i just try to access everything through `class` or `id` knowing that they will be unique. Should i try to make my queries more specific if that's the case?

Comment: If you really want speed avoid libraries. else if you don't have a lot of time libraries save you a lot of time with little impact on performance that is noticeable to end users. and if you want to select a unique element then use the id attribute for the element and use `getElementById`. you can even for e.g `$(document.getElementById("#el"))`

Comment: I think what you need to use is the minimal selector that can select the elements that you want to target.... ie if `.dateP` is unique to that element and it can be used to target that input element then that is sufficient

Comment: Using the verbose selector (ie $('input:text.dateP')) reduces the chances of mistake.  As a project grows and ages its conceivable '.dateP' could be recreated and reapplied without recollection/knowledge of its first incarnation.  Being more specific, when there is not a serious performance concern, is a safer bet imho.